# How to loop through the keys in MongoDB and only access the values for each key in a collection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I have a MongoDB database. Each collection belongs to a single user. Each collection's name is the profile ID of the person, and the `_id` field is the same profile ID. In addition to the `_id` field, the database is structured like so:

```
{
AlbumID1: [track1, track2, track3, track4], 
AlbumID2: [track5, track6, track7, track8],
...
}
```

I have hundreds of albumIDs and each album ID/track ID is represented by a string of numbers and letters.

I want to loop through each AlbumID and access the tracks. Meaning, I want to access:

track1, track2, track3, track4, track5, track6, track7, track8...

I am a beginner and am having trouble figuring out how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you mean Each document in a collection belongs to a single user ? or is it still Each collection belongs to a single user

Comment: Please post your schema or a sample document from your collection. Also, which template library/view engine are you using, (handlebars, pug, ejs etc...)?